# Problem creating an executable jar from scala file

Tags: scala, jar, intellij-idea, executable, executable-jar

I'm tryign to export my project as a jar with IntelliJ 9.0. My project compiles and runs with no problem in Intellij, but when I write it to a .jar and open it, it will show an error.

My Main class is something like:

```
package Main

//Imports

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Main: Hello, world!")
    //do stuff
}
```

Now, in the artifacts window I created a .jar with the following:

1. Main Clas: `Main.Main`
2. Class Path: `lib/javacsv lib/scala-compiler.jar lib/scala-library.jar lib/scalatest-1.0-test.jar lib/scalatest-1.0.jar lib/tools.jar lib/jtds-1.2.2.jar lib/flex-messaging-common.jar lib/flex-messaging-core.jar lib/spring.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar lib/ojdbc14.jar lib/commons-logging.jar lib/postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc3.jar lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar lib/poi-3.6-20091214.jar lib/poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar lib/rt.jar lib/ifxjdbc.jar lib/db2jcc4.jar`

I have double checked that all those classes are on the project and are the onnly classes on it. Notice that it inlcudes `lib/scala-compiler.jar` and `lib/scala-library.jar`.

Build the project: `java -jar myScalaApp.jar` and I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:675)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:288)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:374)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:316)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:288)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:374)
    ... 13 more
```

I understand that it's not finding the scala classes but I made sure they are there. What else can be the problem and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say one of two things has gone wrong:

- `scala-library.jar` is not in your jar; or
- the class path at runtime doesn't include `scala-library.jar`.

I don't know how IntelliJ builds your jar: Does it unpack all your library jars and mung them together with your code into one big jar, or does it add the library jars as-is to your big jar and manipulate the classpath to get at the jars-within-jar?

The first point is easy enough to check: Either use `jar -tvf yourJar.jar` to list out the contents of your jar, or use an archive viewer to look into it graphically. Note that a `.jar` is basically a `.zip`, so you can rename the extension and then use a tool that can look into `.zip` files.

Just had an idea about the second part: Can you build a simple *Java* main class that prints out `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` ? A Java class should be able to run in that jar even if a Scala class isn't.

Comment: When IntelliJ builds a Jar it just adds jars inside the jar.

That's a nice trick. I tried your idea and it returns the jar file. That is, it prints 'myScalaApp.jar'. Does that mean that he is not reding the manifest to get the jar's inside?

Comment: Exactly, there's the problem: Those classes are *not* in yourScalaApp.jar, i.e. they are not directly inside its directory structure. Your classpath needs to contain references to each and every "inside" jar, and I'm not sure of the syntax for that, or if there is one. I've had good success with exploding all of the component jars and re-packing everything into one jar, but unless you have a tool (or an ant task) to do this, it's work.

Comment: And yes, it looks like the manifest is not being respected. Since I'm only being of marginal help, I suggest you try asking this question again without referring to Scala. Lots of people can probably answer this question in a pure Java context.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three ways to do this. (One applies to Netbeans but should work in Idea too)

- Use [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) as explained [here](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/creating-an-executable-jar-out-of-your-scala-code/)
- Use the idea on [this page](http://ssscripting.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/the-not-so-elegant-way-of-creating-an-executable-jar-from-scala-code/) (not so elegant but the easiest) - essentially unpack the Scala directory from scala-library.jar and add this directory to your jar.
- Use the idea on [this page](http://garyboone.com/2009/06/creating-single-file-runnable-jars-in-scala-and-netbeans/) (for NB) - essentially add "scala-library.jar" to your project libraries.